# Fix kextcache "couldn't find symbol" errors after xnu build

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra, kernel-extension, darwin, xnu

I am trying to build and run an [xnu-4570.41.2 kernel](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/) for OS X High Sierra 10.13.3. I am locally compiling it according to guides such as [ssen's blog](http://shantonu.blogspot.com/2015/12/building-xnu-for-os-x-1011-el-capitan.html) and [this more recent tutorial](https://kernelshaman.blogspot.com/2018/01/building-xnu-for-macos-high-sierra-1013.html). Once I compile the kernel, I load it onto a High Sierra 10.13.3 VirtualBox VM, replacing the kernel there so that it boots from my kernel instead.

Although the VM is booting and running my kernel (discernible from differences in `uname -a` output before and after I replace the kernel as well as print statements I add to the boot process), I am seeing the following errors during the kernel extension prelinking process. They appear during the boot process and whenever I run `sudo kextcache -invalidate /` after replacing the VM's kernel with my own per the guides' instructions.

```
kxld[com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily]: In interface com.apple.kpi.mach of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _mach_bridge_register_regwrite_timestamp_callback

kxld[com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily]: In interface com.apple.kpi.private of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _kern_buflet_get_data_length

kxld[com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily]: In interface com.apple.kpi.private of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _kern_buflet_get_data_limit

kxld[com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily]: In interface com.apple.kpi.private of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _kern_buflet_get_data_offset

...

kxld[com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall]: In interface com.apple.kpi.private of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _xcpm_mbox_lock

kxld[com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall]: In interface com.apple.kpi.private of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _xcpm_mbox_unlock

kxld[com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall]: In interface com.apple.kpi.bsd of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _bpf_tap_packet_in

kxld[com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall]: In interface com.apple.kpi.bsd of __kernel__, couldn't find symbol _bpf_tap_packet_out
```

These are just a sampling of the some 18,000 such errors. While these errors don't prevent a working PrelinkedKernel from being built, there is clearly some missing step in the kernel compilation or installation. Why might these errors occur? Does anyone know how I can resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/why-doesnt-apple-release-full-kernel-source-code) from Open Source Stack Exchange talking about some of the `xcpm` symbols I'm missing, I've concluded that these symbols are missing because they are from proprietary files Apple doesn't release with the xnu open-source.

**Update**: These missing symbols errors can be resolved by specifying declarations for them in `xnu/config/Private.exports`. Building the kernel via [kernelshaman's Makefile](https://jeremya.com/sw/Makefile.xnudeps) adds these symbols in for you automatically.

Comment: I don't think this is the only problem. I didn't get these errors when building 10.13.3 but I do when building 10.13.6

Comment: @JLegendre Any ideas on why that might be? What components are you building for 10.13.3? I'm building/installing dtrace, AvailabilityVersions, libplatform headers, libdispatch, Libsystem, xnu-headers, and finally xnu. All versions from 10.13.3 on open source.apple.com. I'm building on a 10.13.5 host, copying and modifying its SDK which may or may not be relevant.

Comment: @JLegendre My version is 9.4.1